# summarize a large array (200,000+) of objects as fast as possible

Tags: node.js

Upstream I am supporting a high frequency API call. Behind the call I will have a large array of objects that I need to efficiently summarize (add) into totals for each object as fast as possible using nodejs.

I am sure i could do this with a few looping functions, but wanted to see if the smart people here could find a more efficient way.

```
[{
samplefield1: 123, 
samplefield2: 345, 
samplefield3: 678, 
samplefield4: 910, 
samplefield5: 111
},
{
samplefield1: 123, 
samplefield2: 345, 
samplefield3: 678, 
samplefield4: 910, 
samplefield5: 111
},
{
samplefield1: 123, 
samplefield2: 345, 
samplefield3: 678, 
samplefield4: 910, 
samplefield5: 111
},
{
samplefield1: 123, 
samplefield2: 345, 
samplefield3: 678, 
samplefield4: 910, 
samplefield5: 111
}.... 
]
```

desired output

```
{
samplefield1total: 1349596065934, 
samplefield2total: 5856960650505, 
samplefield3total: 4344343434343, 
samplefield4total: 44444434342910, 
samplefield5total: 79797696969696
}
```

As an added bonus, it would be amazing if i could also get a count of all the records from the input added to the array like below...

bonus challenge output:

```
{
samplefield1total: 1349596065934, 
samplefield2total: 5856960650505, 
samplefield3total: 4344343434343, 
samplefield4total: 44444434342910, 
samplefield5total: 79797696969696,
recordcount: 145634
}
```

but if this is not really efficient to do in the above, i can do it on the outside with a simple array.length statement

appreciate any help you can offer

Comment: Any operation with large data gonna block the event loop  ,possibly try worker threads :)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each object in the large array has the same keys?

Comment: yes, all of the keyfield ids will be the same in each JSON inside the array

Comment: @MattNicholls please don't tell me you're actually receiving all of this as JSON (as a huge string)

Comment: Hey there, your scenario is not really clear. What do your high frequency call send to you? new items for that array? Are you keeping that array in memory or are you using some sort of database? I mean the easiest thing I can think out of my head is just keeping a `sums` object with the previously calculated sums and just add the new values as you receive them, but I'm not sure that is the actual scenario.

Comment: every 2-3 seconds i get a request for stats on 100 different items (the mix is always different and the datset I am pulling from for each is also constantly changing). I have an async function that will take each item provided and pull the matching dataset from dynamodb which is how i get the input array listed above. I have around a second to do the math for all of these items and provide back a summary (the output from above). Unfortunately I dont think i can store the results and reference them for future calls as the data will have changed for most by the time it is called again

Comment: @MattNicholls Ouch! That is a *lot* of accesses for dynamodb. I would urge you to consider storing the sums using a dynamodb stream and lambda function as detailed in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/8rbnxw/achieving_sum_like_aggregate_functions_with/) or investigate other options like Hive. Any level of caching will result in a *completely massively* more efficient implementation for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is not use array helpers (which have to allocate a call frame for every single instance of simple addition). A simple for-loop is all you need, so you'll need to get the array length anyway.

```js
const data = [{samplefield1: 123, samplefield2: 345, samplefield3: 678, samplefield4: 910, samplefield5: 111},{samplefield1: 123, samplefield2: 345, samplefield3: 678, samplefield4: 910, samplefield5: 111},{samplefield1: 123, samplefield2: 345, samplefield3: 678, samplefield4: 910, samplefield5: 111},{samplefield1: 123, samplefield2: 345, samplefield3: 678, samplefield4: 910, samplefield5: 111}];

let totals = data[0];
let recordcount = data.length;
let keys = Object.keys(totals);
let keycount = keys.length;

for(let i = 1; i < recordcount; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < keycount; j++) {
    totals[keys[j]] += data[i][keys[j]];
  }
}

totals.recordcount = recordcount;

console.log(totals);
```

You're unfortunately not going to get away from this costing `O(N*M)` time complexity, since the requirement is to access each of M fields for N objects to add them.

As noted in the comments by @Shubh, this will block the event loop. If this is a *high frequency* API call with each call requiring this much processing, you should offload it to a worker thread. If possible, consider where you're getting the data from (is it a database?) and see if you can make it do the calculation instead.

Note that if your numbers will get much bigger than your sample data in the post you may have to use BigInts for the sums instead, as JavaScript only affords so much precision in its number type.

Comment: good call out on the bigint, i had not considered that but it would definitely be applicable with some of the fields. also, i am glad i threw out that bonus challenge as i would have missed that its already captured in the loop you have designed. This data is coming direct from a dynamodb, so i dont believe there is an option to have it handle the calculation.

Comment: is there opportunity to save time by calculating the totals for each field in parallel?

Comment: @MattNicholls You cannot parallelize synchronous computations unless you put each field on a separate worker thread, since JavaScript is single-threaded. That is an option if you're willing to pursue it I guess, but it  may have a high memory cost as a copy of the data needs to be sent to each worker.